# Which image caching library for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

I am building a photo album app and find a few image caching libraries, namely:

- [JMImageCache](https://github.com/jakemarsh/JMImageCache)
- [HJCache](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

What one you'd recommend (or other libs not on the list)? I am looking for:

- Efficiency
- Minimum effort in terms of garbage collection
- Support for Blocks preferred

Thanks

Comment: [ZDS_Shared](https://github.com/ZarraStudios/ZDS_Shared) has bandwidth throttling but no synchronous requests (that is, it returns nil for a resource when caching is pending). It works with operation queues so I guess you could add a call with NSInvocation for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Personally, I think [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is the best because it is an absolute no-effort solution, and provides the simplest mechanism for cache handling as it is simply an extension of the UIImageView class.

Comment: It was really less than 10 minutes work to compile SDWebImage, choose and include the right library and add the line to use it. Brilliant!

Comment: Try also SmartStorage(github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage). It automatically caches UIImage/NSData on disk or in memory. It's very smart.

Comment: We are in 2014 now and this lib has a stupid bug, it does not show images containing dots in the filename

Comment: About SDWebImage... you can't control expiration date of cache.

Comment: Any image caching library that lets you control expiration date of cache? @Ricardo

Answer (score 11):

Image async downloading and caching is not a simple task. It needs to be done well otherwise it will defeat its purpose. Therefore I strongly suggest that eventually you build your own. Having said that, I needed a quick and simple solution in order to move forward with the development of my application.

I found these solutions:

- [HJCache](https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache)
- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
- Apple's [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)
- An adaption from Apple's LazyTableImages,[MHLazyTableImages](https://github.com/hollance/MHLazyTableImages)

I tried HJCache, but it didn't offer great scrolling performance when handling large images (1.5M+). For small images it worked great though. Tried both LazyTableImages as well but the integration wasn't simple.

Ultimately, I chose SDWebImage. The integration couldn't be simpler. Once you have linked the library to your project all you need to do is:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Additionally:

- Works with custom cells as well
- Doesn't block the UI
- Offers great scrolling performance
- Image downloading and caching is seamless.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple frameworks that solve this problem. Just to name a few:

Swift:

- [**Nuke**](http://kean.github.io/Nuke/) (mine)
- [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)
- [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)
- [HanekeSwift](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift)

Objective-C:

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
- [PINRemoteImage](https://github.com/pinterest/PINRemoteImage)
- [YYWebImage](https://github.com/ibireme/YYWebImage)
- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 2):

Try also [APSmartStorage](http://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage). It automatically caches UIImage/NSData on disk or in memory.

It has cute Blocks–style API;

```
    // setup data parsing block
APSmartStorage.sharedInstance.parsingBlock = ^(NSData *data, NSURL *url)
{
    return [UIImage imageWithData:data scale:UIScreen.mainScreen.scale];
};
...
// show some progress/activity
...
// load object with URL
[APSmartStorage.sharedInstance loadObjectWithURL:imageURL callback:(id object, NSError *error)
{
    // hide progress/activity
    if (error)
    {
        // show error
    }
    else 
    {
        // do something with object
    }
}];
```

It's quite smart and still simple:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried using SDWebImage.

Agreed that it is very easy to integrate.

However the big issue with this library is that it does not honour "max-age" cache control.

The library is still under development but they are not picking this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to try [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) and [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). Both works perfectly for downloading and caching images from the web.

Answer (score 0):

[**Moa**](https://github.com/evgenyneu/moa)

**Moa** is an image download library written in Swift. It allows to download and show an image in an image view by setting its moa.url property.

Installation
Use CocoaPods to add Moa to your project. Just add the following line to your Podfile.

**pod 'moa', '~> 8.0'**