# Swift iOS - optimal amount of cells in collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have collectionView in my swift app, each cell is composed of a thumbnail image.

Right now I have 100 cells initially, and I paginate results from my backend, so the user can click a next button to get the next 100 images, and I call `collectionView.reloadData()` so I re-use the initial 100 cells.

Is there an optimal amount of cells I should have? I can instead paginate by each 1000, so I have a 1000 cells, but I'm guessing this could cause problems having so many cells in memory at once?

Comment: no problems at all. go for it.

Comment: @Fattie Is there hard limit to the max amount of cells one can have?

Comment: Collection view works lazily, you have only as many cells as there are on the screen. No limits for how much cells are in the whole collection view, except maybe `NSUInteger.max` or something around 1 billion

Comment: @JK140 - there is no limit.

Comment: **Note** - unrelated to your question, you must, of course, use some sort of image caching system.  We personally use HanekeSwift lately, but you might like Kingfisher, SDWebImage etc.  DLImageLoader is traditionally the best-engineered, lightest and fastest, so start with the Swift version of that.  Google for 100,000 QAs explaining how to use image caching in iOS.

Comment: For example, here's a QA about "which image caching library to use".  http://stackoverflow.com/a/39636643/294884  (It's quite silly that both android and ios do not, yet, at the time of writing include image caching just built-in.  it's just one of those things, when people read this in 5 or 10 years they will be completely mystified that you had to "add a library!" to do something so basic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no limit at all.

"1000" is absolutely nothing.

Your only consideration here would be, what is a good chunk size to grab *depending on your bandwidth*.

That is to say, you have **no issues whatsoever with the collection view**. You just want to pick a good chunk size, so that **in terms of networking**, from the user's point of view it feels like it is loading smoothly.  (Try 2500 to begin with and vary it up and down.)  (In really sophisticated apps, you vary that amount dynamically, depending on measurements you make while the app is running, but that is irrelevant here.)

Again you have **absolutely no issues, whatsoever, with the collection view**. Set it to **any value you want**.  Set it to 100 million if you feel like it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Given there is no limit to the amount of cells, is there any good reason at all to have pagination in my app?

Comment: only to help with the downloading.  so, if you have to download 10,000, if you download 1000 at a time it will make it better for the user.  But really, at first just forget it and download everything.  Cheers

Comment: Initially the collectionView was taking a large time to load even with only 100 cells/images because the images are coming from a URL and I was storing high-quality PNG images. I now compress the images and use JPEG so the image size is a lot smaller, and the collectionView loads quickly now. This is why I initially began to question if there is a good reason to limit the initial amount of cells.

Comment: What would you consider to be a large bandwith?